# UIImageView Border Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I'm adding a border to a UIImageView subclass of mine which works great:

```
self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

self.layer.borderWidth = 10;
```

Upon adding a UIImageView to the top of the image however, I noticed that the border is covering the image up!

```
UIImage*pin = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PinDown2"];

UIImageView*view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:pin];

view.frame = CGRectMake(self.bounds.size.width/2, 0, 32, 39);

[self addSubview:view];
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't find any alternative, try this,

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354811/how-can-i-take-an-uiimage-and-give-it-a-black-border/1358967#1358967)

or this,

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354811/how-can-i-take-an-uiimage-and-give-it-a-black-border/1355612#1355612)

Both are from same post. You can also find other answers there.