# How To draw black colored border around each image in AQGridView

Tags: iphone, aqgridview

I am using AQGridView in my project. we need to create a black colored border around each image. Can anyone help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Jas.

Answer (score 1):

for UIImageView it is like something :-

```
[imageView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[imageView.layer setBorderWidth: 2.0];
```

Hope it works on AQGridView...

Cheers

Comment: also refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354811/how-can-i-take-an-uiimage-and-give-it-a-black-border

Comment: It applies for the gridView. but we need to apply border for each image in the AQGridView. Thanks for your answer,

Answer (score 1):

You could also put your AQGridView in a larger UIImageView that was empty but had the background set to black.